# Winhttp Multiple Proxy Servers

Tags: windows, proxy, winhttp

Is there a way to set multiple proxy servers via winhttp? I have an application that looks at the registry key set by winhttp for the proxy server and I can confirm it's working fine when I set it via the command below.

netsh winhttp set proxy host-name-or-IP:port

However, I want it to try one proxy server first and then fail over to another one. Is there anyway to set multiple proxy servers via the registry key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [Microsoft says that Only one proxy server is supported](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winhttp/autoproxy-issues-in-winhttp).

Comment: Thanks. I looked around their page but did not find that specific article.